# В чем разница между annotation-driven и mvc:annotation-driven?

Tags: spring

Настраиваю контекст для `DispatcherServlet..(mvc-dis-servlet.xml)`,
и у меня там есть тег для включения аннотаций `annotation-driven`, и он выдает ошибку.

Поменял на  `mvc:annotation-driven` и idea что то скачала из сети.

В чем разница между этими тегами? Тег  включает все компоненты помеченные аннотацией Spring-a, такие как: `@Component @Repository @Service @Controller @Bean` и.т.д ?

Comment: заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978283/5506820). `context:annotation-driven` включает такие аннотации как `@Bean`, `@Autowired` и т.д., т.е. те, которые нужны для работы базовой экосистемы spring. `mvc:annotation-driven` включает`@RequestMapping`, `@RestController` и т. д., т.е. те, которые нужны для работы каркаса spring-mvc.